# Uma consulta ao banco de dados que traga os dados em sequencia

Tags: sql

Segue um seguinte treco do código:

```
SELECT user_id, name, firstname
FROM vrp_user_identities
WHERE user_id IN (27, 2, 1, 365, 142)
```

Me retorna um array apenas com os dados que eu quero, porém ele vem em forma ascendente ao usar o `IN` ao invés de vir primeiro os dados do `ID 27` ele puxa primeiro os dados do `ID 1` e assim por diante.

Como eu poderia contornar isso?

Comment: Depende de qual engine de SQL está usando. Em boa parte pode usar `ORDER BY user_id=142,user_id=365,user_id=1,...`  - [veja funcionando aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/163d6a/1) - em outros pode usar funções específicas como `ORDE BY FIND_IN_SET( user_id,'27,2...')`, etc. Só que, provavelmente, mesmo que edite a pergunta e saia alguma resposta, não é o que você precisa de verdade, que é o que chamamos de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A ordem precisa ser definida por um `ORDER BY`. Utilize `FIELD` em conjunto, para definir a sequencia de ids.

Veja um exemplo baseado no seu caso específico: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83cfab/1)

```
SELECT user_id, name, firstname
FROM teste
WHERE user_id IN (2, 27, 1, 365, 142)
ORDER BY FIELD (user_id, 27, 2, 1, 365, 142);
```

A ordem dos `user_id` no `WHERE` não influencia o resultado final, o `ORDER BY` que fará isso.

Comment: `ORDER BY` não precisa de "field" basta por os campos a seguir. O Field pode ser usado no mysql, mas a pergunta não diz que é esse banco de dados, por isso resposta não parece resolver o problema